# How to stop a background from scrolling with the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive been trying to get this work as a background on my website and I finally have the sizing and everything down the only issue im running into now is it is scrolling with the page and I want to stay put.

It only does this when I insert it on a code block in my website but when I just inject into my header it stays put while still moving when the mouse hovers over it.

Any help is really appreciated

HTML

```
<h1 align="center">
  Chandra Station
</h1>
<canvas id="stars" width="600" height="800"></canvas>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ironwallaby/delaunay/master/delaunay.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
    <style css>
    html,
    body {
        margin: 2;
        padding: 2;
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: #1e94b8; 
        background: radial-gradient(
            ellipse at center,
            rgb(89, 179, 200) 0%,
            rgb(30, 148, 184) 100%
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        );
    
    }
    
    #stars {
      left: 0;
        position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index:2;
    
    }
    
    
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the background-attachment property in css:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

You can read more about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Also, When pasting in your code try to include only the relevant blocks.. All of the javascript you included makes the question hard to read.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesnt stop the background from scrolling over everything. Also I will make sure to just put the relavant code next time thanks for the feedback

Comment: Are you saying the background is on top of the content?